# How can I write a route to catch *.php?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I want to make a route that catches all "php" files... I've tried:

```
routes.MapRoute("php", "{*x}.php", new { controller = ... });
```

But I get the following exception:

```
A path segment that contains more than one section, such as a literal section
or a parameter, cannot contain a catch-all parameter.
Parameter: routeUrl
```

It must catch:

```
/p1/p2/p3.php
/p1/p2.php
/p1.php
```

I want to write a single rule that can catch `N` levels... How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a constraint:

```
routes.MapRoute("php", "{*allphp}", new { ... }, new { allphp = @".*\.php" });
```

If you still have the default route, this must be placed before.

My answer is based upon: [Make routing ignore requests for a file extension](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx)

Comment: Only loosely based upon that article -- nice solution!